# Array error when picking winning ticket.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

Can anyone spot any errors here? Sorry for asking again but I am new here and wasn't quite sure what to do when posting.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `giveawayusers` (`giveawayid`, `steamid64`, `coins`, `from`, `to`) VALUES (:id, :id64, :coins, :from, :to)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
                ":id"  => $id,
                ":id64"       =>  $steamUserId,
                ":coins"  => $coins,
                ":from"       =>  $currentCoins,
                ":to"  => $totalCoins,
            ));

if($currentCoins+$coins>=$totalCoins)
{
    $winningticket = mt_rand(1,$totalCoins);
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `steamid64` FROM `giveawayusers` WHERE `from` <= :winningticket AND `to` >= :winningticket AND `giveawayid`=:id');
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
        $stmt->bindValue(':winningticket', $winningticket);
        $stmt->execute();
        $winner = $stmt->fetch();
```

I believe the error could be here

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `steamid64` FROM `giveawayusers` WHERE `from` <= :winningticket AND `to` >= :winningticket AND `giveawayid`=:id');
```

My database structure is like:

https://gyazo.com/4ec4874d879b2cf4bd1d2450e57cfa71
https://gyazo.com/95cddb0a1c7b8fd1c360a6d5a1b2e129

Cheers,
James

Comment: What king of error do you get ? I'm not sure what's the question here.

Comment: The winner isn't picked. Have a look at skin-room.com and you'll understand

Comment: So you get an empty result from your query ?

Comment: Yeah. Trying to figure out how to fix it

Comment: Your numbers are too high in coins (2) and current coins (2 or 4). The result of `mt_rand(1,$totalCoins)` to be 0, 1 or 2. Plenty of the data you have in your table for coins and total coins would produce a result higher than 2, return an empty result set from your query.

Comment: I've tried it with only 2 coins in the pot. Have you got steam or Skype? I'll show you the files and how it meants to work

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe we are allowed to reference a named bind placeholder more than once in a prepared statement. (This was true in earlier versions of PDO, not sure if that's fixed in the version you are running.)

I suggest using *unique* bind placeholder names. The same value can be supplied for multiple placeholders. As an example:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `steamid64` FROM `giveawayusers`'
                       . ' WHERE `from`      <= :winningticket1'
                       .   ' AND `to`        >= :winningticket2'
                       .   ' AND `giveawayid` = :id'
            );
    $stmt->bindValue(':winningticket1', $winningticket);
    $stmt->bindValue(':winningticket2', $winningticket);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
```

---

But if that's the problem, then I wouldn't describe the observed behavior as an "Array error".

That description is rather vague, and misleadingly imprecise. If this is the cause of the error, then it's the `execute` that is throwing the error (not the prepare) and I would expect the error message to include mention an invalid number of bound parameters" or something like that. We should include the *exact* error message when describing the behavior we observe, not a vague generalization.

---

If that's not the cause of the error, if the `execute` is successful, then as @TopCheese mentions in a comment, it's valid for a query execution to return an empty resultset. In that case, I don't see how the code shown in the question would throw an "Array error".

Comment: Re: named bind placeholder more than once - it is possible if PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES set to true (which should be default setting).

Comment: Using unique names for bind placeholders is valid with either setting of ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES. My preference is to write a statement that works in either case. I don't think that changing the setting of PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES should "break" a SQL statement.

Comment: Yeah, I might be dating myself with that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE `from` >= :winningticket AND `to` <= :winningticket
```

Comment: Code only answers are very low quality and are candidates for deletion.  There needs to be at least one sentence describing what question you're answering and how this answers it.